# How can I get the byte array value returned from a bluetooth incoming message and edit it before displaying it on the other device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So I asked this question a few days ago, but maybe I can elaborate a bit more, or in a different way now.  I am a big java and android newbie, so it takes a lot of time to figure stuff out for me. I have a Bluetooth connecting between 2 devices. I tried using sensors and everything works fine. The devices connect and they send sensor values to one another.
This sensor value, however, is auto-generated. What I want is to get DB values from one of the devices, convert them to bytes, add them to a byte array and send this byte array as a single message to the other device, where it is going to reverse the process. I have everything set up, everything is as it should be with only 1 exception - I need to somehow catch the incomingMessage as a byte array, so I can finish the process.
How can I get the value of the incomingMessage(which is supposed to be transferring a byte array) and add it to another byte array that I am then "decoding"?

The commented out one is the example that I tried and was working.

```
 if (mBluetoothConnection.incomingMessage != null) {
            //messageTemp = mBluetoothConnection.incomingMessage;
            msg = mBluetoothConnection.incomingMessage;

        }
```

The one that is not commented out is the one, whose value I want to assign to a byte array:

```
  byte[] array = msg;
```

This is the only thing that I have not been able to figure out so far. 
My current issue is that "array" returns null object reference.
Please, help me! I feel like I have almost connected 2 bridges and the paint on each differest by just a centimeter from being okay.

Comment: `I need to somehow catch the incomingMessage as a byte array,` You are doing that already. You receive them in byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];. Use that buffer. `mBluetoothConnection.incomingMessage` That is a String and you will not use intermedeate Strings to transfer your byte array. Use `buffer`. I showed you how to do so. Further you are not telleing the type of 'msg'. and 'incomingMessage'.

Comment: Why did you not continue our conversation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58817543/how-can-i-assing-the-value-of-an-incoming-bluetooth-message-to-a-byte-array-whic?noredirect=1#comment103943757_58817543

Comment: `My current issue is that "array" returns null object reference.` ??? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @blackapps Thought I could as it anew so I can define it a bit better. I tried various things, but everything gives me a result different that what I need. Yes, I am catching the byte, but the IncomingMessage is a String. If I change it to byte I can not pass the byte and buffer values in order to send it as a single byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I managed to figure it out, but forgot to update, here is my other post with a little bit more code:
[How can I assing the value of an incoming Bluetooth message to a byte array which I want to decode into integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58817543/how-can-i-assing-the-value-of-an-incoming-bluetooth-message-to-a-byte-array-whic?noredirect=1#comment104006078_58817543)

Here's what I changed:
I only touched the run() method in my BluetoothConnectionService

Instead of using the byte[] buffer, as I mention in the commented code, I declared a public static byte[] incomingBytes and gave it a size of 44, since this is what my 11 integer array going to need. Then I just replaced the "buffer" with "incomingBytes" in the example code, and looks like this:

```
public static byte[] incomingBytes = new byte[44];

public void run(){
            //byte [] buffer replaced with incomingBytes
            byte[] buffer = new byte[44];  // this was in the example, but it is not used. It was replaced by incomingBytes, declared at the start of the class

            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(incomingBytes);
                    incomingMessage = new String(incomingBytes, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Then I only need to call incomingBytes for my convertion in the other class and it works fine.